# Firefox and magically appearing character (Â) when unescaping an ®

Tags: firefox, forms, pdf, character, illegal-characters

I'm unescaping an `®` (registration character) in firefox to be submitted in a form, since actually typing that character into Javascript causes the script to behave strangely.

However, I must use the unescaped(..) version of the character since it is being submitted to the backend (where I have no control) and the output is a pdf file which uses the unescaped `®` for display in a pdf.

I unescape the `®` character like this:

`unescape("%AE")`

However...when I do view the `®` in the pdf file it appears as `Â®`, this only happens in Firefox, not in Internet Explorer.

Is there anyway of getting this to work in Firefox 2/3?

Thanks,
 
   Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, after unescaping, Mozilla returns the Unicode representation of `®`, but IE not. ("%C2%AE" in hex, and `%C2` means that strange character `Â` appearing in the PDF.) Internet Explorer and Mozilla unescapes strings in a different way. You should set an explicit character encoding, principally UTF-8.

[MDC: escape and unescape Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide:Predefined_Functions:escape_and_unescape_Functions):

> The escape and unescape functions do
>   not work properly for non-ASCII
>   characters and have been deprecated.
>   In JavaScript 1.5 and later, use
>   encodeURI, decodeURI,
>   encodeURIComponent, and
>   decodeURIComponent.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz4x90hk(VS.85).aspx):

> The unescape method returns a string
>   value that contains the contents of
>   charstring. All characters encoded
>   with the %xx hexadecimal form are
>   replaced by their ASCII character set
>   equivalents.
>
> Characters encoded in %uxxxx format
>   (Unicode characters) are replaced with
>   the Unicode character with hexadecimal
>   encoding xxxx.